# Creating overlapping sets with constraints

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

I need to create overlapping sets with constraints that say that similar items should not appear together. I have a local greedy algorithm that works ok-ish, but that surely will break down. I wonder whether there is a global algorithm instead.

I have `n` items that I want to arrange in sets of size `s` (`s=8`; `n>>s`). There is overlap between sets, so that each item appears at least twice across all sets (exactly twice, if `mod(n,s/2)==0`). Furthermore, items should never be placed in a common set more than once.

An algorithm that satisfy this is to randomly arrange the items into sets of `n/2`, and to complete set `i` by picking one element each of sets `i+1` through `i+s/2` (continuing at `i=0` after `i` has reached `n`).

However, there are constraints. For simplicity, say that my items have a color and a shape. There are a lot of colors `c`, and a limited number of shapes `p`, i.e. `s << c < n`, and `p<s`. Thus, while no set should contain more than 1 of each color, I allow a set to have up to 3 of each shape.

My current iteration of the algorithm creates sets sequentially, and then attempts to swap items between sets in order to satisfy the constraints. I believe it would be better to turn this into some kind of assignment problem that can be optimized globally, and possibly, such a problem has already been solved (or at least given a name). Is there such an algorithm?

Comment: Could be solved by backtracking... guarantees to find a solution if there is any, but performance might be bad.

Comment: Isn't there an additional constraint like the items that are in the same set cannot be placed in the same set again, otherwise you could end up with duplicate sets.

Comment: @maraca: good point, will  add.